# Como criar uma minimal API .NET 6, que retorne dados dinâmicos?

Tags: c#, .net, api

Preciso criar uma API em .NET 6 que me retorne dados dinâmicos e não para uma classe específica.

Exemplo digamos que eu tenha uma tabela de vendas e que uma requisição a API peça as vendas anuais de 2010 a 2021, outra requisição peça as vendas anuais de 2015 a 2020, sendo que os anos são retornados na forma de colunas através da técnica de pivot table do SQLSERVER.

Não consigo jogar esse retorno em uma classe específica, pois a quatidade de colunas pode ser diferente de uma requisição pra outra.

Venho do webform e no webform eu jogava o resultado num datatable é isso que estou tentando fazer nessa api.

Abaixo mostro um exemplo do que preciso, O select no exemplo é apenas para exemplificar, pois o select real é mais complexoutiliza a técnica pivot table)

Como fazer o codigo abaixo retornar o JSON de forma dinâmica sem ser para uma classe específica?

```
app.MapGet("v1/todos", (AppDbContext context) => {
    //var todos = context.Todos.ToList();
    string SQL = "SELECT * FROM Itens for json auto";

    var itens = context.Itens.FromSqlRaw(SQL).ToList();
    return Results.Ok(itens);
});
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dificuldade nesse seu caso é que o Entity Framework Core necessita de alguma configuração extra para conseguir executar esse tipo de consulta, na qual você só quer pegar uma única coluna string (já que o SQL Server já retorna o JSON direto) de um consulta em Raw SQL. Por conta disso, ele nunca vai te deixar só jogar o SQL em cima do **FromSqlRaw()** como na sua questão.

Vou explicar duas possibilidades aqui que você pode utilizar, uma com ADO.NET mesmo e outra com o Entity Framework:

1. ADO.NET

Nesse caso, podemos abrir uma conexão através do EF (já que você já tem ele mapeado) e chamar um **ExecuteScalar()** direto nele:

```
app.MapGet("ado/itens", (AppDbContext context) =>
{
    var connection = context.Database.GetDbConnection();

    using DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Itens for json auto";

    connection.Open();

    var itens = cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

    return Results.Text(itens, "application/json");
});
```

2. Entity Framework Core

No caso do EF, desde a versão 3, as consultas sempre devem ser feitas através de um DbSet<>, e isso significa que mesmo consultas que não retornem entidades mapeadas diretamente de tabelas devem ser mapeadas para uma classe com todos os campos retornados.

No caso que você passou, seria só pegar um retorno de uma coluna que é uma string já em formato JSON, então devemos mapear ele como um objeto que possui apenas uma propriedade string:

```
public class ItensModel
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
}
```

A partir daí, você tem duas possibilidades:

1. Você pode mapear a consulta no DbContext e só chamar a entidade como se fosse uma tabela

O context:

```
public partial class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    // mapeia a classe num DbSet<>
    public DbSet<ItensModel> ItensModel { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // configura a entidade do DbSet como uma consulta SQL 
        // note que eu forço ele a retornar o nome da coluna com o mesmo nome da propriedade da entidade
        modelBuilder.Entity<ItensModel>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasNoKey();

            entity.ToSqlQuery("SELECT (SELECT * FROM Itens for json auto) AS Result");                
        });
    }
}
```

Agora é só fazer o EF consultar por essa entidade como se fosse uma tabela:

```
app.MapGet("ef/itens", (AppDbContext context) =>
{
    var itensModel = context.ItensModel.FirstOrDefault();

    var itens = itensModel?.Result ?? string.Empty;

    return Results.Text(itens, "application/json");
});
```

2. Você pode só indicar que a entidade não possui chave e fazer a consulta direto na chamada da consulta no EF.

O context:

```
public partial class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    // mapeia a classe num DbSet<>
    public DbSet<ItensModel> ItensModel { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // configura a entidade do DbSet indicando que não possui chave primária, obrigatório pra não dar erro
        modelBuilder.Entity<ItensModel>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasNoKey();           
        });
    }
}
```

Agora deve ser feita a chamada com o SQL direto:

```
app.MapGet("ef/itens", (AppDbContext context) =>
{
    var itensModel = context.ItensModel.FromSqlRaw("SELECT (SELECT * FROM Itens for json auto) AS Result").FirstOrDefault();

    var itens = itensModel?.Result ?? string.Empty;

    return Results.Text(itens, "application/json");
});
```

**Obs.:** Note que nos dois casos, utilizei o **Results.Text()** como retorno, para que o ASP.NET Core entenda que ele tem que usar a string como foi retornada no SQL que já é um JSON válido direto pra saída. Com o **Results.Ok()**, ele não vai entender a string como um json direto e vai tentar colocar o conteúdo entre aspas.